# Process 'javaw' taking up 95%+ of CPU usage

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, cpu-usage

I have a java game which crunches up to a minimum of 94% CPU on start up. This is indeed a crazy amount considering the program is only 124kb. Possible problems could be that it implements three kinds of threads.

- One to recieve and send packets as a server;
- one as a client;
- and the main game thread.

There could be many different possibilities as to why this is breaking, but my guess is stuck to the Thread idea. Any ideas and suggestions to push this number down are welcome, and **GREATLY** appreciated.

CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.66Ghz RAM, 2gb.

---

Note: This happens on many computers, however the game runs smoothly.

---

**Edit:** In reply to an answer made, I am using no libraries whatsoever, and I have created my threads in a similar fashion. The client and server threads follow this:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
  public boolean running;
  public DatagramSocket socket;

  public Client() {
    running = true;
    socket = new DatagramSocket(/*whatever params*/);
    new Thread(this).start();
  }
  public void run() {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    while(running) {
      socket.receive(data);
      parsePacket(data);
    }
  }
  public void parsePacket(byte[] data) {
    // Does all the packet parsing things.
    // The client modifies the level.
    // The server just spreads things to every client. (could be the server if multiple connections are live?)
  }
}
```

However, when you check to see if the thread is interrupted, wouldn't that check if and only if the thread is paused? - That's what an interrupted thread means, right?

would a `Thread.sleep(50)` at the end of the main game loop do any good? Still open for plausible fixes.

Comment: how many threads jvm is creating when it has higher cpu consumption ? also check if jvm keeps it self busy in just doing GC by monitoring GC activity

Comment: Size is not usually indicative of CPU load. `while (true) {}` takes 100% CPU quite easily!

Answer (score 1):

This is a performance tuning issue that would require the entire codebase to know what you're doing that is spiking the processor.  Right now we know you've written a computer program that spins up three threads.  So I bet it's in one of those three threads because that's all we really know.  We don't even know what game library it's based on.  Without any real code there's no way to provide any real help.

Anyway, here is what you do to start figuring out which thread is spinning off into oblivion.  Typically you'd write a main thread like this:

```
public class MainGameLoop implements Runnable {

    public void startupGame() {
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       doStartUpGame();
       long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.printf("Start up took %,d%n", end - start );
    }

    public void run() {
        startUpGame();
        while( !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() ) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            doGameLogic();
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.printf("Processing took %,d ms %n", duration );
            if( duration < frameRate ) {
               Thread.sleep( frameRate - duration );
            } else {
               System.out.printf("Game loop took longer than it should by %,d ms%n", duration - frameRate );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do that on all your threads and just see which of the three is taking up so much CPU.  After that you can start to narrow it down to what section is eat up your CPU.  Repeat this process for each subprocesses that apart of doGameLogic, etc.

Comment: Thread.isInterrupted() is a flag that is set when someone calls thread.interrupt() which is done when you want a thread to shutdown.  Thread.interrupt() doesn't shutdown a thread it just requests the thread to stop.  Read up threads in the Java API because they aren't that difficult to understand from the API.  The sleep call keeps your thread from burning up the CPU because you only need to update the screen at the frameRate of your game no more.  Without a sleep you are essentially writing while(true) { bang the processor }.  And InterruptedException is very important and tied with above.